# express-session deletes session when refreshing with angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express, session, express-session

I'm trying make a login session with express-session on my angular project, that would keep a user logged in even if the page is being refreshed. The result is that when the page is being refreshed the session is being deleted. Important to say that the session is not being deleted when I'm have a GET/POST requests with Google Chrome or Postman (not through Angular).

I have tried solve this by adding `withCredentials: true` to the request.
Code:

```
handleUserOnit() {
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/users/oninit`, {
      withCredentials: true
    });
  }
}
```

And to the cors:

```
app.use(cors({ origin: ["http://localhost:4200"], credentials: true }));
```

This is GET request code:

```
router.get("/oninit", (req, res) => {
 console.log(req.session);
  if (req.session.logged) {
    console.log(true);
    req.status(200).json({ userName: req.session.userEmail });
  } else {
    console.log(false);
    res.status(200).json({ userName: false });
  }
});
```

So each time a user is logging in, the server is adding some properties to the session like `req.session.logged == true`, But all of those properties are deleted everytime the page is refreshed.
This is the Session object:

```
router.use(
  session({
    secret: secret,
    name: "egsid",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      path: "/",
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60
    }
  })
);
```

Is there a specific way to handle sessions when using Angular? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: by default, express-session use MemoryStore that is reset each time your node.js app is restarted (maybe with grunt/gulp)

Comment: Is there any way to prevent that default without having more node packages?

Comment: install one depending on your stack. See the full list here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores